# Installing DHIS-2 on Amazon-AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dhis-2

I just came across DHIS2 last friday through a client and I knew then that its what I've been looking for all along. I'm now trying to deploy on the cloud for a demo today (hopefully).

Is there a good guide out there to Installing DHIS-2 on Amazon Web Services or Linode or any affordable Cloud for that matter?

I've looked around google, not much help. Stack Exchange has a few users asking for help for their AWS deployment, not quite on point.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/88117/making-dhis2-work-with-postgresql

Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the installation docs at the link below. DHIS 2 runs on Java 8, PostgreSQL and Tomcat. The installation docs is based on Ubuntu / Debian which is available on AWS EC2. It explains how to install DHIS 2 staring from a plain VM, which is what you do on AWS.

http://dhis2.github.io/dhis2-docs/master/en/implementer/html/ch08.html

If you prefer Fedora, the main difference is that you must use the yum package manager instead of APT, which basically translates to using `yum install` instead of `apt-get install`.

The basics of the installation process are as follows:

- Install PostgreSQL with: `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4`
- Create the `dhis.conf` configuration file.
- Tell the system where the configuration file is located by pointing a `DHIS2_HOME` environment variable to it.
- Install Java 8 with:

  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`
- Download the DHIS 2 WAR file from the [downloads page](http://www.dhis2.org/downloads) and place it under `tomcat/webapps`.
- Start Tomcat with `tomcat/bin/startup.sh`

You can also access the public DHIS 2 demo here in case you need to do demos:

https://play.dhis2.org/demo/